# How to call a asp.net web api from kornshell script

Tags: unix

We need to check the technical feasibility to call a Asp.NET web api from korn shell script.
The purpose is to log the start and successful or error end of the Koran shell script via Web API in a log table. 
What can be done to achieve this requirement?
I have not yet tried anything as I am completely new in this territory and is not aware from where to start. Please guide me through this.

Comment: I have come to know that I can do this with curl command. But I  am not sure on how to use it. I have a code in jquery to call an webapi. I need to implement the same in shell script. Below is the snippet of JQuery for calling an webapi:

Comment: I have a jquery code to call a webapi.     
    var LR = {
        "OperationName": <<Log Level>>,
        "InputData": <<Log Message>>
        };

$http({
      method: 'POST',
     url: urlbase + 'api/Logging/ProcessRequest',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': <<Key>>, 'AppName': <<AppName>> },
            data: JSON.stringify(LR),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
   processData: true
        }).then(function (results) {

        }, function (data, status) {
             
        });